# My proof: $\alpha$ is NOT separable over $K\iff\mbox{Irr}(\alpha,K)'=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, proof-verification

My proof goes as follows:

### Proof

If $\alpha$ is a multiple root of $f=\newcommand{\Irr}{\mbox{Irr}(\alpha,K)}\Irr$ then
$$
\begin{align}
f&=(X-\alpha)^2g\\
f'&=2(X-\alpha)g+(X-\alpha)g'
\end{align}
$$
so $\alpha$ is a root of $f'$. Thus
$$
f'\in(f)=\mbox{Ker}(ev_\alpha)
$$
but the ideal $(f)$ only contains polynomials of degree greater than or equal to that of $f$ - except for the zero polynomial. Thus $f'=0$.

Suppose now instead that $f'=0$. In characteristic $0$ this means that $f$ is a constant polynomial so it is not irreducible. In characteristic $p$ it means that $f\in K[X^p]$ since all powers of $X$ that are not powers of $X^p$ have non-zero derivatives. Well, don't know where to go from there with the $\mbox{char}(K)=p$ case...

I wonder if there is an easier way to phrase this...

Comment: I do not understand why would $f'\in (f)$

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Because $f$ generates the ideal of all polynomials having $\alpha$ as a root.

Comment: Oh yes... I think that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f(X)=g(X^p)$ for some $g\in K[X]$ of positive degree. Now look at this equation over an algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$. Then all the coefficients of $g$ are $p$-th powers, and we can write $f(X)=g(X^p)=\tilde{g}(X)^p$ for a polynomial $\tilde{g}\in \overline{K}[X]$ of positive degree. It follows that $f$ has repeated roots in $\overline{K}$.

Comment: That was a clever argument! Thank you!

Comment: I find it rather strange that my textbook stated, that we should prove the $\Leftarrow$ direction as an exercise. I do not think, that I would have considered this myself...

Comment: Does this mean that roots of $f$ come with multiplicity $p$ or could it even be any multiple of $p$?

Comment: Dear @String, The multiplicities are at least $p$, but they could be larger powers of $p$ as well, because $g$ might also satisfy $g(X)=h(X^p)$ for some $h\in K[X]$, i.e., $g$ might not be separable. In general you can write $f(X)=f_{sep}(X^{p^f})$ for some (necessarily irreducible) separable $f_{sep}\in K[X]$ and some $f\geq 1$.

Comment: Ah, ok. I expected something like that, but it is nice to know!

Answer (score 1):

Over $\mathbf{F}_p$, $f(x^p) = (f(x))^p$, so $f(x^p)$ can't be irreducible. This generalises over $\mathbf{F}_q$ for $q = p^k$, $f(x^p) = (g(x))^p$ where the coefficients of $g(x)$ are the inverse of those of $f(x)$ by the Frobenius map.

Comment: I am having second thoughts... This seems to prove that there are NO $\alpha$'s that are inseparable in any fields since $f'=0$ does not correspond to an irreducible polynomial $f$ in any characteristic.

Comment: Also, the Frobenius map only fixes the coefficients if they are in $\mathbb F_p$ not if they are in a general characteristic $p$ fields, right?

Comment: Inseparable elements do not exist over any field of characteristic zero or any finite field. They can exist only over infinite fields of characteristic $>0$. And yes sorry $f(x^p) = (f(x))^p$ only over $\mathbf{F}_p$. But over $\mathbf{F}_{p^k}$ even if the coefficients are not fixed, you still have a factorisation of $f(x^p)$.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that! I wonder how the inseparable elements come into play then in those infinite characteristic $p$ fields...

Comment: For an example, consider $L = \mathbf{F}_2(y)$ (the field of rational functions with coefficients in $\mathbf{F}_2$ in inteterminate $y$), which is infinite of characteristic $2$. Let $t = y^2$, and consider $K = \mathbf{F}_2(t)$. $L = K(y)$ is an algebraic extension of $K$, and the minimal polynomial of $y$ over $K$ is $x^2-t \in K[x]$. But in $L[x]$, $x^2-t = x^2-y^2 = (x-y)^2$, so $y$ is a multiple root.

Comment: By rational functions do you mean the fraction field of $\mathbb F_2[X]$? I am not familiar with the concepts involved... Sorry!

Comment: Yes, it's the most obvious example of an infinite field of characteristic non-zero (there is also the algebraic closure of $\mathbf{F}_p$, but you can't do many things in it since it's already algebraically closed).

Comment: Ok, thanks again!